# R: One-Sided T-Test for grouped data

Tags: r, t-test, grouped-table

I have the following problem. My data-set contains 3 variables. The participant ID, the participant's sex and one measured value. The data-set looks something like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'ID sex value
01 m 0.0765
02 f 0.063
03 f 0.0773
04 m 0.0599
05 m 0.0679
06 m 0.067
07 f 0.0728
08 m 0.0589
09 f 0.0699', header=TRUE)
```

Value one is a list of correlations. So with a one-sample t-test I would like to test whether they are on average significant. Thus, my hypothesis would be μ < or = 0.1. The alternative hypothesis is of course that μ > 0.1.

Please don't try to discuss whether this is a statistically reasonable procedure. I am supposed to perform this exact procedure!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am not sure on your hypothesis. Also, from a design perspective, it could be appropriate to differentiate between sex, i.e. `split(df, sex)` or `x = df[df$sex == "f", ], y = df[df$sex == "m", ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for

```r
t.test(df$value, mu = .1, alternative = "greater")
#>  One Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  df$value
#> t = -14.258, df = 8, p-value = 1
#> alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 0.1
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.06397722        Inf
#> sample estimates:
#>  mean of x 
#> 0.06813333
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

That is `alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 0.1`.
Change to `alternative = "less"` if that's what you are after.

Rule to remember:

> "If $p$ is low, $H_0$ must go."